# NSColorWell in an NSTableView in swift

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nscolorwell

Anybody have any good suggestions for getting an NSColorWell into an
NSTableView? Most other widgets work great, since thery're based
around cells, but NSColorWell doesn't have a corresponding
NSColorWellCell.

Comment: It's highly recommended to use a modern view based table view. There are (almost) no restrictions.

Comment: the problem is "almost" and this is the case with nscolorwell

Comment: There is no problem at all to use an `NSColorWell` in a view based table view.

Comment: if there is a problem
I can not do get or set color there is no cell
otherwise or I can play with
  nameColorWell.color = NSColor.blue it's not ok

Comment: where is my mistake ?? could you tell me a little more

Comment: In a view based table view you can use target/action and `rowForView` to identify the row. Please watch the WWDC 2011 video about view based table views

Comment: if in a column
there is only NSColorWell yes it works
in another column there is NSTextField and NSColorWell can not get the NSColorWell view
for an action with NSColorWell there is no problem in both cases

Comment: I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0):

In a **view based** table view the most convenient solution is Cocoa Bindings. You can bind the `value` of the color well to an `NSColor` instance of your model.

Without Cocoa Bindings create an `IBAction` method in the target view controller

```
@IBAction func colorDidChange(_ sender: NSColorWell)
{
    let row = tableView.row(for: sender)
    let column = tableView.column(for: sender)
    print(row, column, sender.color)
}
```

In Interface Builder control drag from the color well to the view controller and connect the action. The action will print `row`, `column` and the new color. `tableView` is the `NSTableView` outlet.

If there are multiple color wells in the same view you could assign different tags to distinguish the color wells

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did

my problem is in the same cell I have NSTextField and NSColorWell
for IBAction no problem

    @IBAction func actionColorWell (_ sender: NSColorWell) {

         let row = colorTable.row (for: sender as NSView)
         color [row] = sender.color
+ a lot of interaction
     }

to assign a value without making Cocoa Bindings.
myView (NSColorWell) .color = color ??
myView = ???? The whole problem is there

I do not know how to do

Comment: No, you have to update the model (not the view) which is supposed to be a custom class, and then reload the row with`self.tableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: IndexSet(integer: row), columnIndexes: IndexSet(integer: column))`. In `viewFor tableColum` assign the values of the model to the UI elements. But I strongly recommended Cocoa Bindings. It's so much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem without Binding Cocoa
I updated the view and everything works fine by upgrading NSTableCellView (the last 3 lines)
in the real program which is a program of account there is too much relation between the tableview and the outlineview, the filters that made me redo a lot of work by making the binding

Thanks for your help

```
class ColorsController:  NSWindowController  {

@IBOutlet var colorTable: NSTableView!

let tableViewData =
    [["firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailId":"john.doe@mail.com"],
     ["firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe","emailId":"jane.doe@mail.com"]]

var color = [NSColor.red, NSColor.blue]

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    self.colorTable.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func actionColorWell(_ sender: NSColorWell) {

    let row = colorTable.row(for: sender as NSView)
    color[row] =  sender.color
    colorTable.reloadData()
    let select1 : IndexSet = [row]
    colorTable.selectRowIndexes(select1, byExtendingSelection: false)
    }
}

extension ColorsController : NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate{
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return tableViewData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{

    let identifier = (tableColumn?.identifier)!
    switch identifier.rawValue {
    case "firstName" :
        let  result  = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        result.textField?.stringValue = tableViewData[row][(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]!
        result.textField?.textColor = color[row]
        return result

    case "lastName" :
        let  result  = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        result.textField?.stringValue = tableViewData[row][(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]!
        result.textField?.textColor = color[row]
        return result

    case "emailId" :
        let  result  = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as! KSDataCellView
        result.textField?.stringValue = tableViewData[row][(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]!
        result.textField?.textColor = color[row]
        result.colorWell.color = color[row]
        return result

    case "color" :
        let result = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as! NSColorWell
        result.color = color[row]
        return result

    default:
        return nil
    }
}
}

class KSDataCellView: NSTableCellView {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorWell:NSColorWell!
}
```

Comment: FYI: With Cocoa Bindings you can reduce your code in `ColorsController` to the declaration lines of `tableViewData` and `color` however it's highly recommended (and required with bindings) to use a custom class for all string and color values

Comment: Populating a table view using Cocoa bindings is considered an advanced topic. Although using bindings requires significantly less code—in some cases no code at all—the bindings are hard to see and debug if you aren’t familiar with the interface. It’s strongly suggested that you become comfortable with the techniques for managing table views programmatically before you decide to use Cocoa bindings. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html